# sql query for codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to build query like below

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    propertylist
WHERE
    (propertyfor = 'RENT')
        AND (state LIKE '%AA%' OR city LIKE '%AA%'
        OR address1 LIKE '%AA%'
        OR description LIKE '%AA%'
        OR address2 LIKE '%AA%')
ORDER BY transdt DESC
```

in codeigniter?

I Build like

```
$this->db->where('propertyfor',$type);
$this->db->like('state',$val);
$this->db->or_like('city',$val);
$this->db->or_like('address1',$val);
$this->db->or_like('description',$val);
$this->db->or_like('address2',$val);
$this->db->order_by('transdt', 'DESC');

$query = $this->db->get('propertylist');
```

Any Help?

Comment: not any error.Result is not like expected

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$this->db->where('propertyfor', $type, FALSE);
$this->db->where("state LIKE '%{$val}%' OR city LIKE '%{$val}%'
                OR address1 LIKE '%{$val}%'
                OR description LIKE '%{$val}%'
                OR address2 LIKE '%{$val}%'", NULL, FALSE);
$this->db->order_by('transdt', 'DESC');

$query = $this->db->get('propertylist');
```

UPDATE:
Unfortunately, the Codeigniter is no other way to implement the complex conditions in where, from or any other.
Your code:

```
$this->db->where('propertyfor',$type);
$this->db->like('state',$val);
$this->db->or_like('city',$val);
$this->db->or_like('address1',$val);
$this->db->or_like('description',$val);
$this->db->or_like('address2',$val);
```

Converts by Codeigniter into SQL:

```
WHERE propertyfor = {$type}
    AND state LIKE {$val}
    OR city LIKE {$val}
    OR address1 LIKE {$val}
    OR description LIKE {$val}
    OR address2 LIKE {$val}
```

Comment: This might work, but codeigniter has built in functions for `or_like`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->db->from('propertylist');
$this->db->where('propertyfor', $type);
$this->db->like('state', $val, 'both');
$this->db->or_like('address1', $val, 'both');
$this->db->or_like('description', $val, 'both');
$this->db->or_like('address2', $val, 'both');
$this->db->order_by('transdt', 'DESC');

$query = $this->db->get();
```